# How to achieve UIDatePicker with date and time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I am wondering that why the default `UIDatePicker` view will not allow the date and time.

I am trying to get the below `UIDatePicker` for my application.

Your advice will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: do you want to display `date` and `time` in single `UIDatePicker` or you need both as in above format `dd MMM yyyy HH mm` ?

Comment: I need single picker that display date and time as shown in above figure

Answer (score 0):

You can change the mode of it

```
@property(nonatomic) UIDatePickerMode datePickerMode;
```

//

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `datePickerMode` property of UIDatePicker.

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
picker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime //for both date and time
```

Other modes are `.date` (for date only), `.time` (for time only) and `.countDownTimer` (for count down timer).

From Storyboard you can change from Attribute Inspector.

[image]

Comment: try to set mode programatically.

Comment: I tried it, not show what I expected,  since years will not change in this case